# PHP XML DOM parsing issue

Tags: php, xml

I am kinda new in xml parsing, I am trying to figure out what is wrong with this piece of code why is it refusing to display any result?

```
//php code
    $file=file_get_contents("http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/sitemap.xml");
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($file);
    $xmlPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $arrNodes = $xmlPath->query('//loc');
    foreach($arrNodes as $arrNode){
        echo $arrNode->nodeValue;
    }
```

---

```
//sitemap.xml
    <url>
    <loc>http://calculosophia.com/</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>http://calculosophia.com/finance/compound-interest-calculator</loc>
    </url>
```

I can see that the file is getting retrieved successfully but when var dumping $arrNodes it gives me `object(DOMNodeList)[170]` I dunno what to do further

Comment: can you please explain why -1 ?

Comment: Change `$arrNode->item(0)->nodeValue` to `$arrNode->nodeValue`

Comment: @RocketHazmat still nothing

Comment: What do you see if you do `var_dump($arrNode)` inside the loop?

Comment: Nothing it doesn't loop inside @RocketHazmat

Comment: I see your issue.  Your XML file is *invalid*.  There's no root node.  Is what you've posted here the entirety of your XML file?

Comment: If you add a root node to your XML file, your code works.  Try doing `$dom->loadXML('<xml>'.$file.'</xml>');`.  DEMO: https://eval.in/238184

Comment: Nope it has a root you can check it http://calculosophia.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: Not sure why xpath isn't working, but you can try `$arrNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('loc');` instead.

Comment: I think it was because the sitemap.xml wasn't wrapped with xml file. but is it a problem if I submit my sitemap.xml to google while it has xml wrapped ?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Oh Wait I see the problem was because the code is wrapped within <urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"> as soon as I removed it everything started working

Comment: No, wait.  I see the problem.  You need that `<urlset>` tag.  Your XML file was correct.  The problem was that for xpath to work you need to register the namespace being used!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arrNodes = $xmlPath->query('//loc');
```

This line is returning you a DOMNodeList containing 0 elements.  That's because the root element (`<urlset>`) is declaring a namespace (the `xmlns` attribute).  XPath needs to know about this namespace before you can use it to query the file.

```
$xmlPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
// The 1st parameter is just name, it can be whatever you want
// The 2nd parameter is the namespace URL (the value of the "xmlns" attribute)
$xmlPath->registerNamespace('sitemap', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');
$arrNodes = $xmlPath->query('//sitemap:loc');
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I am old in PHP and this thing would never come to my mind though I don't know why they -1 me ? is it kinda of stupid ?